# Check Design on IPhone or Simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Is there anyway to check design for my iphone App on Simulator or IPhone, actually i m developing an IPhone app, my colig is busy in designing for my app but how she can check that design is ok or not before embeding into my application. Please Help

Comment: This makes no sense - "how she can check that design is ok or not before embeding into my application. " - She needs to know to design something for the application. Its not the other way around.

Comment: Why dont you sit with the designer and finalize if its ok or not.

Comment: why not ask your designer to create the graphics with the iPhone frame? embed the graphics (eg BG, buttons, bars etc) inside the iphone frame like she is drawing the app by placing the view elements to places? she dont need a simulator or device then, just the iPhone frame image is enough.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need `WireFrame` tools for designing mockups for screens. The design is totally based on the the 'elements' placed inside the iPhone screen.

Go to google and search for `"Wireframe tools for iOS applications"`.

Try  [LucidChart !](http://www.lucidchart.com/pages/examples/iphone_mockup_tool)

Answer (score 0):

Your colleague can provide you with the graphical resources and you can check that they look okay on your device or on your simulator.

Comment: Yes there is no easy way for a designer to check the designs on a simulator

Answer (score 0):

Setup a shared dropbox folder, that way you can easily check your designs on an actual device.
If you want to check on the simulator you can simply open it up in safari, that's how I used to do it.